# How can I get the corresponding location in bytecode by a given source code column number

Tags: java, bytecode

I want to instrument some code in the middle of a line of code by ASM, and the insert location is given by source code column number. For example, there is a line of code:

```
if(logger!=null && logger.getName()!=null)
```

I need to insert some code between two condition checks at position of column number 12, which is between `a!=null` and `&&`. This line's corresponding bytecodes are:

```
1 ALOAD 0
2 GETFIELD Main$Thread1.this$0 : LMain;
3 INVOKESTATIC Main.access$0 (LMain;)Ljava/util/logging/Logger;
4 IFNULL L1
5 ALOAD 0
6 GETFIELD Main$Thread1.this$0 : LMain;
7 INVOKESTATIC Main.access$0 (LMain;)Ljava/util/logging/Logger;
8 INVOKEVIRTUAL java/util/logging/Logger.getName ()Ljava/lang/String;
9 IFNULL L1
```

My question is, is there any programmatic way to find out source code column number 12 is corresponding to the position between line 4 and 5 in bytecode? Is there any ASM API supports such functionality?

My current solution is generating a new source file where the original line is broken at column 12, so two new lines of bytecode such as

```
L2
LINENUMBER 41 L2
```

are added between original line 4 and 5. I can get the corresponding position by comparing two versions of bytecodes. I think there should be a smarter and simpler way.

Comment: Given that expression evaluation does not have to proceed left-to-right (precedence rules), I'd be really surprised if you can do this.  I think the granularity level will always be a statement, and even that gets iffy if optimization removes or reorders statements.  Also it's not clear where "between the `a!=null` and `&&`" is.  It could be before evaluating the second operand or between the second operand evaluation and the application of logical AND.  That's a clear example of the evaluation not proceeding left-to-right.  I think the question is not answerable in its present state.

Comment: I suggest you add the statement you want it to look like, e.g. you want `if(logger != null && logger.isDebugEnabled() && logger.getName() != null)`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why are you trying to instrument column numbers?

Comment: Who is providing that column number? The source of that number should provide the information in a smarter way instead, i.e. oriented towards the actual task.